# How do I get the OTP send within AWS Cognito so that I can do my own manual checking?

Tags: amazon-web-services, flutter, amazon-cognito

I am happy with using AWS Cognito as a service for my flutter application. However, now I realize that the AWS SNS service is really pricey for usage within my country (No free tier and price is significantly higher than in the West), hence I wanted to use another 3rd party service which is cheaper to send any SMS to users. This will include Phone Number Verification during signup, Forgot Password Verification and other flows. I know that I can accomplish the phone number verification using the lambda function. However, for the forgot password flow, the only way of me changing the password is through sending a request to AWS which includes the OTP and new password.

How can I accomplish this? Can I change the user password explicitly in AWS by not going through the forgot_password flow in AWS (Meaning I send my own OTP and check the OTP myself, then updates the password), or how can I get the OTP generated by the forgot password then send it through the 3rd party SMS service?

Comment: I am facing the exactly same issue. Have you gotten any solution on it?
I want to bypass otp send by `resetPassword()` or else autoVerify OTP by calling any lambda trigger but I am not able to find any one related to this one.